# Java ternary operator not working?

Tags: java, stringbuilder, ternary-operator

Let's assume we have an StringBuilder and an double. Now want to append the double. If the double can be represent as Integer (for example 3.0, 5.0 etc.) i want to add it as Integer, otherwise as double.

The first method to realize this is:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
double d = 3.5;

if (d % 1 == 0) sb.append((int) d);
else sb.append(d);

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

This works still good, when `d` is `3.0` 3 will be append, if `d` is `3.5` 3.5 will be append.

Now i want to do this shortly with the ternary operator:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
double d = 3.5;

sb.append(d % 1 == 0 ? (int) d : d);

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

So now i have an issue, every time, if double is `3.0` or `3.5` it will be added as double value! Only when i *theoretically* cast on `true` AND `false` it works... but every time and that is not what I want. What is here the problem? Why does the ternary operator not work?

Comment: You should be using `DecimalFormat("0.#")` to get rid of the trailing zeros, instead of casting to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that an expression with a ternary operator has a well-defined type.  The JLS describes in some detail how this type is evaluated, but in rough terms, it's the least upper bound of the type of the expression before the colon and the type of the expression after the colon.

For example, if `b` is `boolean`, `i` is `int` and `d` is `double`, then the type of `b ? i : d` is `double`, because `double` is the least upper bound of `int` and `double`.  When you call `append( b ? i : d )` on your `StringBuilder`, you get the version of `append` with the `double` parameter.  The same thing happens in your case, with `d % 1 == 0 ? (int) d : d`.

Answer (score 5):

This behavior is documented in the JLS - 15.25. [Conditional Operator ? : :](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

> If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T

When you write

```
(a > b) ? 'a' : 65
```

the second type is converted to a char.

Go through the JLS, it explains the behavior (same approach) in other cases.

Comment: Strangely enough, if I evaluate `d % 1 == 0 ? (int) d : d` (where d = 3) in eclipse, is returns "3".  But then appends "3.0".  But that's probably an Eclipse thing.

Answer (score 1):

When using the ternary operator on primitive numbers, the 2nd and 3rd operand are subject to binary numeric promotion. In your case, the `int` is cast to a `double`. This is specified in the [JLS #15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

Answer (score 1):

Method `StringBuilder.append()` has many overloads for different type of parameters. Which method overload is used is a compile-time decision. The result of ternary operator has just a single type, either `int` or `double` - `double` in this case.

In the case of `if` statement, compiler uses the proper `append()` method overload depending on the branch.

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler regards `sb.append(d % 1 == 0 ? (int) d : d)` as `sb.append(double)` ,otherwise  `sb.append((int) d)` as `sb.append(int)` .

Answer (score 0):

Numeric conditional expressions are standalone expressions (§15.2).

The type of a numeric conditional expression is determined as follows:

If the second and third operands have the same type, then that is the type of the conditional expression.

If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

If one of the operands is of type byte or Byte and the other is of type short or Short, then the type of the conditional expression is short.

If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

If one of the operands is of type T, where T is Byte, Short, or Character, and the other operand is a constant expression of type int whose value is representable in the type U which is the result of applying unboxing conversion to T, then the type of the conditional expression is U.

Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.

The types are converted to their corresponding primitive ones, which is called unboxing.
If one operand were a constant int (not Integer before unboxing) whose value is representable in the other type, the int operand is converted into the other type.
Otherwise the smaller type is converted into the next greater one until both operands have the same type. The conversion orders are:

byte -> short -> int -> long -> float -> double

char -> int -> long -> float -> double

Eventually the whole conditional expression gets the type of its second and third operands.